# html5 dataset with play framework

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0, html-datalist

I have a list of languages, and with a combobox I can see the codes :

```
 @select(
            searchForm("langCode"),
    options(for (lang <- langs) yield (lang.langCode)),
            '_default -> "--- Choose a Language ---",
            '_label -> "Language"
    )
```

And now i want use a datalist HTML to autocomplete a text area with the codes. I have tried with this but it doesn't get the @lang.langCode value:

```
@inputText(searchForm("langCode"), '_label -> "Language") 
   <datalist id=langCode>
   @langs.map { lang =>
        <option>
          @lang.langCode
         </option>
    }
   </datalist>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, sorry, i'm new here. It's with play framework in scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, except:

1. Add `list` attribute to `@inputText` arguments:

   @inputText(searchForm("langCode"), '_label -> "Language", 'list -> "langCodeDatalist")
2. Make sure `id` used for `datalist` is different from the one used for the input box:

   < datalist id="langCodeDatalist">

Once I made these changes, it worked. Check the source code to make sure `@lang.langCode` is getting pasted correctly.